# Request Scoped bean cannot use in Response body [Spring Boot]

Tags: java, spring-boot, requestscope

I have a Request scoped(prototype) bean as a Response for a Rest Controller and getting Exception , not working

I tried spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false on the property file as suggested by the error message *"Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.epic.dcms.kyc.beans.MainResponse$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$82085c99[\"targetSource\"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource[\"beanFactory\"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory[\"beanExpressionResolver\"])"*,

didn't work then there was a cyclic dependency and exception was thrown

@RequestScope annotation to @scope annotation change didn't solve the issue also

I notice that this exception only comes when the MainResponse used as a Response.

```
  Bean
        @RequestScope
        @Component
        public class MainResponse implements Serializable{
        //fields and getters and setters
        }

  Controller class
         @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
            public MainResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws FileStorageException {
                String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

                response.putPayLoad(true,"fileName",fileName)
                        .putPayLoad("ContentType",file.getContentType())
                        .putPayLoad("size",file.getSize());

                return response;
            }
```

when I remove @RequestScope from MainResponse bean it just works fine, any idea how to fix this??

Comment: Why is MainResponse  a bean?

Comment: it is Request scoped (prototype) bean , so that it's being managed by framework,any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Usually the request and response objects are not managed by Spring because they don't have a lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mark your response class with "@RequestScope", data binding will be managed by framework itself.